# how to use seq with xargs to curl request

Tags: curl, xargs, seq

I'm working on `curl` commmand
that performs an action based upon parms value

```
curl 'http://www.example.com/actionid?id=123'
```

`id` value i want to pump dynamically so

`seq 1 10 | xargs -I + curl 'http://example.com/actionid?id=123'`

In output I'm getting

```
curl 'http://example.com/actionid?id=+'

curl 'http://example.com/actionid?id=+'

curl 'http://example.com/actionid?id=+'
....
```

how can I pass it as value I also tried

```
seq 1 10 | xargs -I + curl 'http://example.com/actionid?id=123'`< <(printf '+\n' $(seq 1 10)
```

I'm getting the same results.

**solution**

placed `'` around -I `'~'` and its working now.

Comment: Please explicitly state what you are trying to achieve and double-check your commands. The last contains a syntax error, the second does not match the output.

Answer (score 2):

```
printf '%d\n' {1..10} | xargs -i -- echo curl http://example.com/actionid?id={}
```

remove `echo` when and put a real url.

Answer (score 1):

Use a loop:

```
for i in $(seq 1 10) ; do
    curl http://example.com/actionid\?id=$i
done
```